# Source To Image not finding C++ libs

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, s2i

I am creating a custom Builder Image using S2i dotnet core. This will run in OpenShift linux container

I have modified the custom builder image and included few lines to copy few dlls and ".so" files

When running the container in OpenShift I am facing the below error

error says

```
"unable to load shared library 'CustomCppWrapper' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, 
consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libWrapperName: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

I have set the LD_DEBUG environment variable and found below few errors

```
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: error: version lookup error: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /opt/app-root/app/libCWrappeNamer.so) (fatal)
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: error: version lookup error: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./libCWrappeNamer.so) (fatal)
```

I did below command and found below

`ldd libCWrappeNamer.so`

```
./libCWrappeNamer.so: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./libCWrappeNamer.so)
./libCWrappeNamer.so: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /ab/sdk/customlib/gcc540/lib/libabc.so)
./libCWrappeNamer.so: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /ab/sdk/customlib/gcc540/lib/libxmlc.so)
```

Below is my Custom Docker file builder image

```
FROM dotnet/dotnet-31-runtime-rhel7
# This image provides a .NET Core 3.1 environment you can use to run your .NET
# applications.

ENV PATH=/opt/app-root/src/.local/bin:/opt/app-root/src/bin:/opt/app-root/node_modules/.bin:${PATH} \
    STI_SCRIPTS_PATH=/usr/libexec/s2i

LABEL io.k8s.description="Platform for building and running .NET Core 3.1 applications" \
      io.openshift.tags="builder,.net,dotnet,dotnetcore,rh-dotnet31"

# Labels consumed by Red Hat build service
LABEL name="dotnet/dotnet-31-rhel7" \
      com.redhat.component="rh-dotnet31-container" \
      version="3.1" \
      release="1" \
      architecture="x86_64"

#-------------------------- COPY CPP LIBS

COPY CustomCppWrapper.lib /opt/app-root/app
COPY libCWrappeNamer.so /opt/app-root/app


#----------------------------------


# Labels consumed by Eclipse JBoss OpenShift plugin
LABEL com.redhat.dev-mode="DEV_MODE:false" \
      com.redhat.deployments-dir="/opt/app-root/src"

# Switch to root for package installs
USER 0

# Copy the S2I scripts from the specific language image to $STI_SCRIPTS_PATH.
COPY ./s2i/bin/ /usr/libexec/s2i

RUN INSTALL_PKGS="rh-nodejs10-npm rh-nodejs10-nodejs-nodemon rh-dotnet31-dotnet-sdk-3.1 rsync" && \
    yum install -y --setopt=tsflags=nodocs --disablerepo=\* \
      --enablerepo=rhel-7-server-rpms,rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms,rhel-7-server-dotnet-rpms \
      $INSTALL_PKGS && \
    rpm -V $INSTALL_PKGS && \
    yum clean all -y && \
# yum cache files may still exist (and quite large in size)
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*

# Directory with the sources is set as the working directory.
RUN mkdir /opt/app-root/src
WORKDIR /opt/app-root/src

# Trigger first time actions.
RUN scl enable rh-dotnet31 'dotnet help'

# Build the container tool.
RUN /usr/libexec/s2i/container-tool build-tool

# Since $HOME is set to /opt/app-root, the yum install may have created config
# directories (such as ~/.pki/nssdb) there. These will be owned by root and can
# cause actions that work on all of /opt/app-root to fail. So we need to fix
# the permissions on those too.
RUN chown -R 1001:0 /opt/app-root && fix-permissions /opt/app-root

ENV ENABLED_COLLECTIONS="$ENABLED_COLLECTIONS rh-nodejs10" \
# Needed for the `dotnet watch` to detect changes in a container.
    DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true

# Run container by default as user with id 1001 (default)
USER 1001

# Set the default CMD to print the usage of the language image.
CMD /usr/libexec/s2i/usage
```

Comment: What Linux distro you've used to build your ```libCWrappeNamer.so``` shared library?

Answer (score 1):

Your code depends on libstdc++.so.6 but it would seem that version isn't installed

In your Dockerfile, add the `yum install` command that should do it. It would depend on what operating system you're using, but for RHEL 7, for example, you could do:

`RUN yum install -y libstdc++`

With more details of the operating system I can give a more specific command

In this specific examples the Dockerfile could look something like this:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum install -y libstdc++

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```